# Add virtual environment path in node-red python shell node windows

Tags: python, node.js, node-red

How to add virtual environment in the python shell node in node-red window? Actually me already specify my virtual environment path to the node then when tried to run the python script it return exit code: -4058 error.. but when remove the virtual environment path it can run perfectly. Need help because really need to run the python script within my virtual environment ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to enable the virtual environment in the shell before starting node-red, so all the required environment variables are updated.